# Selenium Webdriver - unable to click certain elements on PHP site

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Test website: automationpractice.com

In the practice website above, there are two elements that I can successfully locate, but not click: the main logo "Your Logo" as well as the shopping cart link. The .click() method seems to have no effect on these elements; navigation does not occur.

Testing using Selenium 3.0 beta2, FirefoxDriver

Any ideas?

Comment: Code please ?? or how else do you expect us to help you

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code, and it worked for me.

```
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
WebElement elem  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='My Store']"));
elem.click();
```